# How to obfuscate an APK in Android 2.1/2.2

Tags: android, obfuscation, apk

We know in SDK 2.3 we can obfuscate APK with Proguard.

The question is: How to obfuscate APK in Andorid 2.1/2.2 SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the file (in the project root) **project.propierties** and add the line

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

And its done. When you try to generate the signed apk of your app it will take a little longer and it will be obfuscated.

If you receive the "Conversion to dalvik error" when generating the apk you need to update the proguard of your sdk. For doing it you need to go to the [ProGuard page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to the download section. Download the last stable version and put it content in

```
SDK_ROOT/tools/proguard
```

Deleting the existing content before of course.

You can check the Proguard manual at their page (link is above) and the [Android's Proguard page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) for more info about ProGuard

Comment: Yes, I received "Conversion to dalvik error" actually. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: But how can we verify that the obtained APK is an obfuscated APK? Kindly update.

Comment: Open the APK file with a common unzip tool.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to verify if the code was obfuscated do this:
download:

1.
dex translator tool - http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/

then this tool to view the classes:
JDGUI- http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui

2.
after you install dex2jar unzip it etc and remember the folder its in.
open up the apk file using winzip or winrar.  You'll see a file there called classes.dex
copy that file into the same folder that dex2jar is in (the dex translator tool you just downloaded).

3.
In the same folder click on setclasspath.bat

Open up a command prompt and traverse to the same folder that dex translator is in and run:
dex2jar classes.dex

-another file shows up now.  Open up JDGUI and open up the file that got generated its called classes_dex2jar.jar ....

4.
you can observe if the decompiled code is obfuscated(readable) now.